# Difficulty removing an un-needed array

Tags: server, raid, mdadm

I'm having a bit of trouble getting rid of a 2-disk raid1 array.

(Ubuntu Server 16.04)

I created an array from 2x 3tb drives using mdadm - the array was just for data storage, and not part of my OS / boot system.

However, I then realised it had only picked up an array size of 2tb - so followed some steps to (what I thought would) remove the array, then changed both disks to gpt.

Rebooted, and got chucked into emergency mode as it couldn't load device md0

After *lots* of messing around I was able to (seemingly) remove the expectation of an array existing, and have now booted back into my system - phew!

I thought that was that - but not quite.

I've since created the new partitions on the 2x disks, and they show as 3tb - however the system still believes they're part of an array. For example...

sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 31 13:22:09 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2147351488 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2147351488 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Sun Jul 31 19:56:08 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : ARES:0  (local to host ARES)
           UUID : db925a50:039ab51d:bc8b06da:80bacf04
         Events : 3059

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

and

lsblk

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk
└─sda1    8:1    0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0     2T  0 raid1 
sdb       8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0     2T  0 raid1 
sdc       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0   1.8T  0 part  /datamounts/s2
sdd       8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdd1    8:49   0   7.3T  0 part  /datamounts/media
sde       8:64   0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sde1    8:65   0 115.4G  0 part  /
├─sde2    8:66   0     1K  0 part
└─sde5    8:69   0   3.9G  0 part  [SWAP]
```

I've check mdadm.conf, but doesn't appear to be anything incriminating here...

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Sun, 31 Jul 2016 10:13:10 +0100
# by mkconf $Id$
```

So there's clearly still something referencing the array - but I'm not sure what steps I should take to remove any link to it, but without breaking my system again (still very new to all this, as you may gather!)

I can run mdadm --stop /dev/md0, but don't want to run --remove until I know this is the right thing to do!

Thanks for any tips / help on offer!

**Edit to add ...**

Seen a lot of references to /proc/mdstat, so sounds like I should include the contents of this file too.

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      2147351488 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/16 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

**Edit 2**

One of the steps that was suggested in removing mdadm, was

```
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda/
```

but always got an error saying it could not open for writing. The drive wasn't mounted, so wasn't sure how to proceed, and whether it was part of the problem

If I've understood right, the above command will 'wipe out' the superblock info, which is perhaps what's being read to assume they're still part of an array.

So I'm trying to zero the entire drive(s) using

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

and I'll see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the answer for me was to do the following...

run the usual steps to stop and remove a raid array

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --remove /dev/md0
```

at this point, a restart of the machine 're started' the raid again

previous instructions to use `--zero-superblock` failed for me, so tried filling the disks with 0's ...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda status=progress
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

(I ran both at the same time on different terminals - took around 12hours on 3tb drives)

and this did the trick - several reboots later, and no trace of the array.

Re-formatted/partition the disks, and I'm back where I wanted to be.

I'll be honest - not sure whether to re-do the array as 2x3tb disks as originally intended, or to simply run a weekly backup to disk 2 (it's not critical data, or changing that often) - but do at least feel a little more armed this time should I give raid another go.